# Unconfirmed btc transactions

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Reason - Due to unconfirmed inputs.

Can someone please explain what this means and could the sender do this intentionally. In other words to scam someone.

Answer (score 3):

If there are three addressess `A`, `B` and `C` and someone sends a transaction `tx1` from `A` -> `B` and another one `tx2` from `B` -> `C` that spends the exact same coins (tx2 input is tx1 output) then `tx2` cannot be confirmed until `tx1` is confirmed.

Yes someone could trick you to accept an unconfirmed transaction as final and then send the same coins elsewhere (with a higher fee). That’s why you should not consider transactions final unless they are confirmed with at least a few confirmations (6 used to berecommended)